# Best MVC way to handle multiple requests between view and model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have a .net application with a *Form layer*, a *DB model layer* (entity framework) and a *Controller layer* between this two layers.

I need to handle this situation:

1. User presses a button to edit some params
2. The form needs to request some DB data that represents the current state of those params

   - Possibly, the user request could be rejected because is N/A to current situation, in this case an error message box should be shown
3. A modal form is shown, the user changes params and confirm
4. Changes are made in the DB model

That's pretty simple.

The fact is that, at point 4, we need some of the data *we already processed* at point 2.

In particular:

- at point 2 we request some data to the DB model, that data is likely *not* to be in cache, so a SQL query is performed
- that data is processed by a local LINQ
- state of several checkboxes to show in the modal form is returned
- at point 4 we need again LINQ processed data
- since we came from the Form layer, we do not have that data anymore
- therefore data is requested again to the DB model, but this time it's in cache
- that data is processed again by local LINQ

Is it worth to re-load and re-process data to maintain the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how it works exactly in VB.NET, but if we look at this problem in a pure "MVC" way (at least, how I understand it), something is not right.

1. In this step, when the click is done, the form call the controller (all action pass by the controller)
2. The controller then needs to do the validation. If it needs the database to do that, so be it. Then, it redirect the user to a view. (Should it be a message box or another form to enter data)
3. Here, the user do the change in the form and then click on a button to submit. In this button, you call the controller again (another function/action).
4. In the controller, you can do the needed validation and insert/update the data in the database via LINQ. Then, you can redirect to the view.

Since a lot of time could have passed between the step 2 and step 4 and that the data could have changed between the 2 calls, I think that doing the request 2 times is ok. Also, since they are 2 different function in the controller, I don't think you have the choice.

That's how I see it, but I can be wrong :)

***EDIT***

I didn't know that the query to the database were time consuming and that it was an issue.If the absolute goal is to NOT make the user wait twice since time is important in this application, I guess you could store the object that you get at step 2 in memory and retrieve it with the controller (with some kind of helper class). It's like doing the query in the database, but in the memory. If you use the [repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), then the programmer who's coding the logic in the controller will not even know that he's querying something else than the database since it's another level of abstraction. You could free the memory right after the step 4.

Comment: Scenario is a bit different. At step 2 I retrieve some data from DB. Then I do a time-spending parse on that data (not really time-spending, just saying 10 seconds, but I wouldn't make the user wait twice) that gives me a result object, name it `dataResult`, and I use it to *check* if the popup form can appear. Later at step 4, I need again `dataResult`, this time to *calculate* what to write in the DB model.

Comment: Data consistency here is not an issue, since the whole model is transaction-driven, moreover this software MUST be used by one user (admin) at a time. This is already enforced in another piece of the software.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that the request was time consuming. If your absolute goal is to NOT make the user wait twice since time is important, I guess you could store the object that you get at step 2 in memory and retrieve it with the controller. It's like doing the query in the database, but in the memory. In that way, you don't break the MVC model but instead retrieve the data from a temporary repository instead of the real database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, presumably next week.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I'm not 100% sure but the flow pattern in your question does not look right?

The usual procedure is to DISPLAY the DATA and have an edit button there with the dataview

So you may have something like

```
Function ShowAddressDetails(OwnerId as long) as ActionResult
```

And your ActionResult is usually a MODEL that is to be passed to the VIEW
maybe (keeping with the address record sample) something like...

```
Return View(AddressRecordModel)
```

where the address record is extracted from SQL DB using the OwnerId parameter

And in your VIEW where your EDIT button is,
You have at least two choices,
Those being

```
1. Reload data from SQL (used where data may have changed since last action)
2. Pass the already loaded Model (Used where the data hasnt changed)
```

which would mean tha you have either (or both) of the following

```
Function EditAddressDetails(OwnerId as long) as ActionResult
```

or

```
Function EditAddressDetails(Model as AddressRecordModel) as ActionResult
```

Alternatively you may have "CHILDACTION"s as opposed to "ACTION"'s

Also do not forget the following...
in a HTTP GET request, the model is passed from the CONTROLLER TO the VIEW
in a HTTP POST request the Model is passed from the VIEW to the CONTROLLER
So you should indeed have the model (data)?

Finally if the sequence is ONLY used by ONE user then the data should not have changed between requests UNLESS and EDIT/AMEND/UPDATE request was completed successfully.